# Is it possible to set up a DSL lab environment?

Tags: pppoe, adsl, lab

I'm trying to figure out if I can setup a DSL lab for training purposes.

If I have a switch or laptop running a PPPOE server, could I go from ethernet-to-modem then connect the modem's WAN port to another modem's WAN port and have it connect via PPPOE?

Has anyone tried doing something like this before?

Comment: You need a DSL infrastructure, not your idea.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

> If I have a switch or laptop running a PPPOE server, could I go from ethernet-to-modem then connect the modem's WAN port to another modem's WAN port and have it connect via PPPOE?

No. A DSL modem is the CPE part of a DSL link. You can't connect two CPEs, only CPE to COE, e.g. a DSLAM. DSLAMs usually require substantial infrastructure, so a lab environment may be costly.

However, leaving out the problematic DSL link and focus on the higher level function (like PPPoE) you could use a simple Ethernet port as "WAN". Most business-grade services nowadays use some kind of Ethernet as handover protocol anyway.

If need be you could try simple VDSL media converters as COE along with a VDSL modem. This approach isn't easy to build but it's possible.